# Sitecore 8 pagerendering workflow or diagram

Tags: view, sitecore, rendering, sitecore8

I'm learning Sitecore 8, but it's harder than I thought it would be.
I don't get how Sitecore is rendering pages. 
I searched online, but it's hard to find good information.

Does someone have a sort of diagram which explains how Sitecore is rendering pages? So when it gets a request, what is he doing first and how does he couple the different view parts, controllers, renderings together?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you seen this diagram? http://sitecorevn.blogspot.com/2014/09/sitecore-mvc-request-pipeline-execution.html

Comment: Also: http://insitecore.tumblr.com/post/37734162227/sitecore-httprequestbegin-pipeline-in-detail and http://sitecoreskills.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/a-sitecore-8-request-from-beginning-to.html

Comment: going through a tutorial like this might help http://www.matthewdresser.com/sitecore/carousel-sitecore-mvc-(part-1-view-renderings)

Answer (score 0):

You can check these slides about Sitecore MVC:

http://www.slideshare.net/ruudvanfalier/sitecore-mvc-user-group-conference-may-23rd-2014

This diagram shows how a Sitecore MVC request is executed:

[image: A Sitecore MVC request]